# Combination problem: 50 applicants, two sets of 3 identical jobs.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having difficulty with the following question:

A small computer company has 50 applicants for 6 jobs, 3 identical programming jobs and 3 identical engineering jobs, in how many ways can all 6 jobs be filled.

My attempt at the question has been:
$$ {50 \choose 3} + {50-3 \choose 3} $$ but this yields a result of $ 35815 $ and according to the answers it's actually $ 317814000 $
I don't quite understand how they got to this result or what is wrong with my approach.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you *adding* those two numbers? Each choice of $3$ programmers can be combined with any choice of engineers.

Comment: You have to MULTIPLY the binomial coefficients. Brian explains why.

Comment: Whoops, I see it now. A silly mistake on my part. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to deal with this type of problem is to build a model and calculate the probability from first principles.  Particularly useful if you have trouble remembering the formulas.  So:

Arrange the applicants in a line;  give the first three the programming jobs and the second three the engineering jobs; send the rest away.

Thus, there are $50!$ ways to arrange the fifty applicants.

The $44!$ ways to arrange the rejects make no difference;  they lead to identical job assignments

The $3!$ ways to rearrange the first three applicants makes no difference;  they lead to identical job assignments.

Similarly, the $3!$ ways to rearrange the second three applicants makes no difference;  they lead to identical job assignments.

So the answer is $\frac{50!}{44! \times 3! \times 3!}$

Comment: I've never seen it done this way before, but I do like this solution and I will definitely keep it in mind. Thank you.